# how to add thickness to this object

Tags: modeling

i need to add 2mm thickness all over and i have try it extrude+scale+move, solidify. any idea and guide step by step how to do it? or how to add the file here,will be better and easier for helping me. thanks.[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe putting a Solidify Modifier on it (as opposed to using the Solidify command in Edit Mode) gives you more control/options to achieve what you need. Like checking the box next to Even Thickness for example.

Comment: you can share your file here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: i have done this in Solidify and try thru it the simple and complex too.don't work. or is something with this file and i'm too new to understand this.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3yoeag3P" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3yoeag3P/)